# ¿Como validar si un text area tiene valores con angular?

Tags: angular

Tengo el siguiente `textarea`

```
<textarea ng-model="comment" name="comment">
```

Donde requiero aplicar un estilo a un botón con `ng-class` al momento de introducir un valor en el `textarea`

```
<a on-touch="confirm()" style="width:160px; cursor: pointer;" 
   class="btn {{ngDialogData.estiloBotonConfirm}}" 
   ng-class="{'pasoDeshabilitado': !activoCheck || comment == '' }" >
     Aceptar
</a>
```

Cree la variable `scope.activoCheck`, a la cual le asigne `true`, pero al momento de depurar el valor de `scope.comment` no contiene valor.

En el controlador declaro la variable `$scope.comment="";`

Comment: No has puesto el código de funcionamiento de `Js`, ni tampoco, que el resultado que dices que no contiene, valor, deberías hacer un `console.log();`

Comment: Hola Pedro, en el controlador declaro la variable del ng-model del textarea como $scope.comment="";

Comment: De igual forma coloca código `Js`, de esa forma, se podrá saber un poco mas.